# how to add coupons Limit to a single customer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, discount, coupon

I'm using magento 2.1.9

And now one of my customers want to merchants return but we aggred that I won't give him a money but I'll give him a coupon equal the money so he will be able to use it to purchase any thing else how can I do this ?

**Add coupons Limit to a single customer**

Comment: You have a single coupon code for the customer and set the limit for use to 1. That makes the coupon code only valid for 1 time, and if you only tell to this customer then that should be fine.  Or do i understand something wrong in your question?

Comment: know you understood right i thought it was like prestashop that i can define the coupon for just one customer

Comment: and BTW i see in many shopping Sites when we refund some thing thay give  me like prepaid credit equal to i've paid i think it would be better because if i give him coupon with 50$ and he want something with 40$ he will lose the 10$

Comment: Are you using Community or Enterprise? Because store credit is also an option for your case.

Comment: i use Community  edition

Comment: Ok, then Store credit is not an option as it is not available for Community/Open Source. Might want to use the coupon code, or get an extension for store credit.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps for creating coupon for specific user

- First of all you need to create customer group
- Assign specific customer to that group
- Now in your cart rule you can select created customer group

So coupon will apply only for specific customers.